# Why dont use volatile access methods for a volatile array `CounterCell[] counterCells` in Java ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

In JDK8 ConcurrentHashMap using a variable named `volatile Node<K,V>[] table` for The HashMap, and supply three Volatile access methods for the table elements;
Because The volatile array dont means The element of the volatile array is volatile also, So We have to use `Unsafe` class to access elements with volatile semantics.

```
    static final <K,V> Node<K,V> tabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i) {
        return (Node<K,V>)U.getObjectVolatile(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE);
    }

    static final <K,V> boolean casTabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i,
                                        Node<K,V> c, Node<K,V> v) {
        return U.compareAndSwapObject(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE, c, v);
    }

    static final <K,V> void setTabAt(Node<K,V>[] tab, int i, Node<K,V> v) {
        U.putObjectVolatile(tab, ((long)i << ASHIFT) + ABASE, v);
    }
```

[Volatile access methods In ConcurrentHashMap JDK8](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#l754)

But there also have a volatile variable named `volatile CounterCell[] counterCells`, But I dont see any volatile semantics access in counterCells array elements ,

```
            if ((as = counterCells) != null && (n = as.length) > 0) {
                if ((a = as[(n - 1) & h]) == null) { // here as[(n - 1) & h] not volatile access
                    if (cellsBusy == 0) {            // Try to attach new Cell
                        CounterCell r = new CounterCell(x); // Optimistic create
                        if (cellsBusy == 0 &&
                            U.compareAndSwapInt(this, CELLSBUSY, 0, 1)) {
                            boolean created = false;
                            try {               // Recheck under lock
                                CounterCell[] rs; int m, j;
                                if ((rs = counterCells) != null &&
                                    (m = rs.length) > 0 &&
                                    rs[j = (m - 1) & h] == null) { //here rs[j = (m - 1) & h] not volatile
                                    rs[j] = r; // here not volatile
                                    created = true;
                                }
                            } finally {
                                cellsBusy = 0;
                            }
                            if (created)
                                break;
                            continue;           // Slot is now non-empty
                        }
                    }
                    collide = false;
                }
                ......
            }
```

[access volatile array counterCells element is not volatile semantics](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#l2524)

I wonder why just use volatile accsess method for `table` array, but not `counterCells` both, And When is it appropriate to use volatile accsess method visit a volatile array element? Thankyou.

Comment: I find it difficult to read JDK's concurrency code (mainly due to style), but I'd guess `U.compareAndSwapInt(this, CELLSBUSY, 0, 1))` acts as a spinlock protecting the modification of the array so no need to really use volatile there.

Comment: The solution with the `table` uses compare-and-swap, while the `CounterCell` uses `LongAdder`, which performs better under highly contended environments [per the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html). There's also a semantical issue with `ConcurrentHashMap` performance across several different `ConcurrentHashMap` objects that came up years ago, but I'm having trouble finding it at the moment...

Comment: FYI: There is no such thing as a volatile array in Java. When you write `volatile CounterCell[] counterCells`, it's the _variable_ that's `volatile`, not the array to which the variable refers. The volatile semantics are triggered when some thread does `counterCells=...;`, not when `counterCells[i]=...;`.

Comment: A stale read is fine because on table expansion the same cell instances are used and are summed on read. Which cell instances are incremented or decremented does not matter, as long as the summarized state remains consistent.